# Не найден индекс в post-запросе

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

У меня ошибка: не найден индекс `alid` в post-запросе. Все перепроверил - все вроде бы должно работать, так где тогда ошибка?

Js:

```
var alid = data.likeid;
$.post("../php/video.php", {"like": like, "addidprs": idprs, "alid": alid, "idv": str},
                                function(dl){
```

Php:

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    $alid = $_POST['alid'];
    $alid = json_decode($alid, true);
```

Comment: Может проблема в том, что вы используете `json_decode` для значения, которое не является json-строкой? Нужен полный текст ошибки

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['like'] && $_POST['alid'])` используешь два ключа в посте так и проверяй что они установленны

Comment: и стоит сделать `var_dump($_POST)` и показать вывод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подозреваю, что проблема в синтаксисе.
Ajax запрос передаёт объекты, а не строки, тоесть код должен быть без двойных кавычек, например

```
var alid = data.likeid;
$.post("../php/video.php", {like: like, addidprs: idprs, alid: alid, idv: str},
                                function(dl){
```